# Will startActivityForResult() always lead to onActivityResult() called before anything else?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I know this question seems vague, so please bear with me.

I'm working with nested fragments using the v4 support library and running into the bug described [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40537) in which results from `startActivityForResult()` are not routed to the correct child fragment. In that thread, users propose several workarounds, and two of them (replies [#8](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40537#c8) and [#12](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40537#c12)) describe solutions which are based on associating a request code with the path to the nested fragment that made a `startActivityForResult()` call, and then when `onActivityResult()` is called, looking up the path by the request code and routing the result to the correct activity.

This approach seems like it could run into problems if several child fragments made calls using the same request code because it would be ambiguous which child to route results to with that code. However, this would not be an issue if we know for sure that whenever we call `startActivityForResult()`, that `onActivityResult()` will always be called before the fragment gets a chance to call `startActivityForResult()` again.

So my question is, is this a reasonable assumption to make? My mental model for `startActivityForResult()` is that we pause the current activity, do something else, and then immediately upon resuming we get the activity result. Is this correct, or is there some situation where `onActivityResult()` will not be called until some time later after resuming? Are there realistic situations where I would call `startActivityForResult()` from a fragment and then call it a second time from the same fragment before I get a result from the first activity?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to get results back from a fragment you display is to call [`setTargetFragment()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setTargetFragment%28android.app.Fragment,%20int%29) on the new Fragment and then, when you intend to finish with a result in the new Fragment, you call [`getTargetFragment()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getTargetFragment%28%29) to check that it is not null then you call [`getTargetRequestCode()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getTargetRequestCode%28%29) to find out what the request code was.  You can then call `onActivityResult()` directly on the target instead of using the usual approach of setting a result for the Activity to pick up.

So the code would be something like this:

#### FragmentA.java

```
public void showNewFragment() {
    FragmentB newFragment = new FragmentB();
    newFragment.setTargetFragment(this, REQUEST_CODE);
    getChildFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                           .add(R.id.frame, newFragment)
                           .commit;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Handle response as normal
}
```

#### FragmentB.java

```
private void finishWithResult(Bundle resultData) {
    if (getTargetFragment() != null) {
        // Pass the result back to the parent Fragment
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setData(resultData);
        getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    } else {
        // Finish as normal
        setResult(resultData);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution for getting a result back from a fragment. However, I'm trying to get a picture from the camera using an implicit intent, and so I think I specifically need to use `startActivityForResult()`.